# How to stop calling backing bean while clicking p:commandButton?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I use p:commandButton inside p:datatable. the commandButton is used to update the value. At first, when i click the commandButton it calls the corresponding update method. When i click the commandButton second time, the dataTable backing bean method is being called and at last update method is called.

For ex, i have multiple rows in dataTable. If i click first row update button, it get updated in db. If i click the second row update button, it calls the dataTable backing bean method and then the update method.

Here is the code:

```
<p:commandButton value="Select"  
     id="ajaxBtn" 
     action="#{patientMedicineManageBean.selectDrugsImage}" 
     rendered="#{!(patientMedList.medicineImageId.length() eq null)}"  >
        <f:param name="imageName" value="#{patientMedList.imageName}"></f:param>
        <f:param name="medsId" value="#{patientMedList.id}"></f:param>

</p:commandButton>
```

Thanks.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the question mark?

Comment: That was not meant literally, but your post is lacking of a clear and understandable problem description.

Comment: I got the solution.I was making the list as null at the end of the method.Now i removed that it's working fine.That's why the dataTable backing bean method was calling all time while clicking the commandButton.Thanks